# Locate MS Word Mail Merge Data Source

Tags: sql, vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I have a number of Word Documents that perform mail merge operations on startup by running an SQL query against a data source.

I have access to the underlying VBA code in the template but I can't seem to determine where exactly the actual database being queried is located.

How can I find the verbatim of the SQL query being executed and/or the location of the data source?

Comment: Do you understand each line of your code? Can you rule out that no line in your code executes the query? If yes, does your code call on any other resources/execute any other scripts?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the warning message that appears and displays the data source location was turned off via the registry.

To clarify, the VBA code does not have any reference to the data source itself.

[This is what appears for the user under normal circumstances.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIZoq.png)